# python how to add IF statement in a map function using lambda

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, lambda, find

I have this following df:

```
d = {'role': ['admin/tech', 'admin', 'programming/asst/design']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

My goal is:

[image]

In other words, extract everything before the first '/' IF row contains '/'

I came up with:

[image]

and now I need to add a IF statement for this function

I tried something like:

[image]

But it doesn´t work.

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate suggestions!!

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots.

Comment: Python's conditional expressions need an `else` statement, hence the error. Otherwise what should happen if `x.lower` is not `True`? https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html

Comment: I strongly believe it's some IDE error. the code on terminal is different from code on text editor. delete and rewrite the line might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `lambda` function for what you want to achieve.
Try this:

```
>>> df["role"].str.split("/").str[0]
0          admin
1          admin
2    programming
Name: role, dtype: object
```

If for whatever reason you still want to use `lambda`, do this:

```
>>> df["role"].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[0])
0          admin
1          admin
2    programming
Name: role, dtype: object
```